# Push fit auto close valve connector required

Tags: equipment

This is a question about gear more than brewing, per se... I'm wondering if a particular component exists...

I'm trying to find a connector suitable for my system that will allow me to disconnect my vessels simply by pulling out the tubing - so the removal of the tube triggers the closure of a valve in the connector. Without going into too much detail, the system I'm considering at the moment will essentially require two inline closing mechanisms for each vessel so I'd rather have one tap and an auto-close connector. If such a thing doesn't exist I might reconsider my approach.

I've seen a garden hose/spray gun connector that does exactly this but it's not really suitable for potable water - when you disconnect the spray gun the water flow stops even when still under pressure.

Any ideas? Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

[Here's McMaster-Carr's selection of quick-disconnect fittings](http://www.mcmaster.com/#standard-quick-disconnect-hose-couplings/=t4xzxl). In the filters on the left, you'll find a filter for "Flow: with shut-off valve".

There are a number of options that are rated for liquid and have an integrated shut-off valve, but I think you'll find them all to be wicked expensive.

Comment: Quick answer, jsled - thanks! Although I'm in the UK you've given me enough info and keywords to be able to search for similar devices. Funnily enough I've found a manufacturer of food grade hoses and connectors only about 8 miles from my own home :)